# show that the density measure is $\sigma$-additive?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space, $f : X \to [0, +\infty] $ be a measurable function and $$\nu : \Sigma \to [0, +\infty] \;\;\;\;\;\; A \mapsto \nu_f(A) = \int_A f d\mu $$

1st question is to show that $\nu_f$ is a measure.

well $\nu_f(\emptyset) = 0$ since $\mu(\emptyset)$

let $\{ A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \Sigma$ be a sequence of disjoint sets

$\nu(\bigcup_{i \geq 1} A_i) = \int_{\bigcup_{i \geq 1} A_i} f d\mu = \int_{X} f \chi_{\bigcup_{i \geq 1} A_i} d\mu = \int_{X} \sum_{i \geq 1} f \chi_{ A_i} d\mu =  \int_{X} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f \chi_{ A_i} d\mu$

now if $f$ was non-negative I would use the monotone convergence theorem to conculde the $\sigma$-additivity but in this case I'm a bit lost.

EDIT : I'm dumb because $f$ is in fact positive according to the given data.

but what if $f$ was any measurable function ?

Comment: What role is played by $\phi$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. sorry $\phi$ plays a role in the second part which I haven't reached yet. I meant to type $f$ there

Comment: You state "if $f$ was non-negative I would use the monotone convergence theorem" and your first line includes the hypothesis $f : X \to [0,\infty]$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. okay I'm stupid and thanks for noting. however I'm not gonna delete this answer because I'm still interested in the case if $f$ wasn't positive.

Comment: You should ask a new question then, since this one is somewhat ill-posed.

Comment: I will edit it. is that okay ?

Comment: It is your question; do as you see fit.

Comment: If $f$ is negative on a set which has positive measure, then $\nu_f$ cannot be a measure, why? So you must have $f$ is nonnegative a. e. to let this question make sense.